# Why is variable empty for Set Range? [ISSUE HAS BECOME MOOT AND RESOLUTION NO LONGER NEEDED]

Tags: excel, vba, range

NOTE: I added some code below to provide a better idea of what I am attempting to do.  If there is a better way to do this, please share.

Although this is about the same project, it is a different topic, so I am starting a new thread.  The issue with the other thread still is unresolved.

This issue is a possible path towards the solution to the other problem, but the issue is totally different and will effect other parts of this project.

```
Dim rngcellsItemSKu As Excel.Range
Dim rngnameItemSKU
Dim rngnameItemSKUAsString As String
Dim ST as Recordset
Dim db as Database

Set rngcellsItemSKu = Excel.Range(Cell1:="V!A10:A15")

rngnameItemSKU = rngcellsItemSKu

rngcellsItemSKu.Name = "ItemSKU"
rngnameItemSKU = rngcellsItemSKu.Name

set db = DBEngine.OpenDatabase([DBFILENAME], False, False, "Excel 12.0;")

ST = "SELECT * FROM [V$] WHERE "" & rngnameItemSKU & "" IS NOT NULL"
Set rst = db.OpenRecordset(ST)
```

The `set rng****` line where the issue starts.  When I am in debug mode, it has no value.  When I place the mouse cursor over the `rngcellsItemSKu` variable it shows nothing.  Later on when I attempt to name the range so I can refer to it, the code crashes.  Why is this happening?

Comment: I've never used named parameters on the Range call, so I am just giving you the simplest solution for most situations. `Set rngcellsItemSKu = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("V").Range("A10:A15")`

Comment: Still returns no value for rngcellsItemSKu Not sure what is going on.

Comment: What do you mean by *"returns no value"*? The method suggested by @MacroMarc to access the range is correct if you are running VBA from Excel. Are you running VBA from `Access` or `Excel`?

Answer (score 0):

Woah, what a strange method you're using :) First time see sth like that :)

Try this:

```
Dim rngcellsItemSKu As Range
Dim rngnameItemSKU
Dim rngnameItemSKUAsString As String

Set rngcellsItemSKu = Sheets("V").Range("A10:A15")
```

Comment: i am more than willing to use a different way to accomplish my goal.  What I am trying to do is assign a range-name to each column, so I can use SQL SELECT language to select "fields" where columns are the fields.  From what I have been reading, I thought assigning Range-Names which will be used in place of fiends, because the first row in my spreadsheet are not the column names.  So if there is a better way to do that, I will scrap the above code! Thx.

Comment: BTW, this is a result of reading over 50 web links so I am more confused than ever! I am doing my best not to bother people with my questions, but I am now rereading links, so i can't find solutions to these problems! I need HELP! :-\